# Getting "raw" xml from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamic, invocation

I'm trying to to generate web service proxy class using ServiceContractGenerator.
But the problem is that i want to recieve a "raw" xml from webservice (it may be a string or XmlNode, doesnt matter).
Is there any way to modify web service contracts before generating proxy or do something else to get what i need?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Wsdl then it should either been exposed from the webservice. or rather provided to you via .wsdl file.

Comment: Well. I'm consuming wsdl via WsdlImporter, then generating code and compiling it to assembly using ServiceContractGenerator and CodeDom. The point is that in wsdl service response has complex type and during invocation of web method this response is being serialized into object with unknown structure (for me) I just need to have this response in xml format without serializing. I was thinking about changing message type in contract so it will serialize it into XmlNode object, but modifying just message type in service contract doesnt seem to be enough to implement my idea.